# r cumsum differentiate reset at >0

Tags: r, cumsum

I am quite new to R and tried some formulas form the forum but somehow I could not modify them to meet my condition.
I want to construct a cumsum which starts new when the variable in column E  is >=0:

```
NR E Proability Cumsum    
1  -.2 .2 .2   
2  -.15 .2 .4     
3 -.1   .2 .6    
4 .1  .2 .2   
5 .2  .2 .4
```

The last column should be the result.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Column `E` just switch ones between negative and positive values in your data? If so, try `ave(df$Proability,sign(df$E),FUN=cumsum)`. If instead you want to restart the `cumsum` each time `E` changes sign, try `ave(df$Proability,cumsum(c(FALSE,sign(df$E[-1])!=sign(df$E[-nrow(df)]))),FUN=cumsum)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Nicola!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very useful function called `rleid` in the `data.table` package which you can make use of for the grouping. I'll use it in combination with some base functions:

```
library(data.table)
df <- transform(df, cumsum2 = ave(Proability, rleid(E > 0), FUN = cumsum))
```

Or, if you want to fully use data.table functions, it would be

```
setDT(df)
df[, cumsum2 := cumsum(Proability), by = rleid(E > 0)]
setDF(df) # optional
```

Comment: Thank you. However with your first function it gives out the Probability function again as a column?